# How to handle FieldCurrency in CSOM to Set Currency format using Enum

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

How to set Currency Format like ₹ 123,456.00(India). We can set it by using the Sharepoint Online. I want to know how to set it by using CSOM. Is there any `enum` Type to set `CurrencyLocaleId`. Thank You.

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://rohith.sharepoint.com/sites/site"))
        {
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);
            ListCreationInformation listinfo = new ListCreationInformation();
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Custom List");
            context.Load(list);

            FieldCurrency fieldCurrency = context.CastTo<FieldCurrency>(list.AddField("Price", "Currency"));
            //Here how to set Currency Format
            fieldCurrency.CurrencyLocaleId = 1081;

            fieldCurrency.Update();
            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();

            ListItem listItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            listItem["Title"] = "Books";
            listItem["Quentity"] = 12;
            listItem["Price"] = 100;

            listItem.Update();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```